# Installing a widget from an APP

Tags: android, widget, installation

I know i'm going to die as maybe i didn't place this post correctly, also i'm not a developer, only a graphic designer.
I'm looking for some advise, hope someone could help me with that.

Imagine that you launch your app, and within that there is a button that says "Install widget". You press that button, then the app closes and a widget appears on the home screen.

Is that possible?
i've been reading that before 4.2 i wasn't, but something changed from then. Problem is that i have no more information about this, and also i don't know if it changed over time.

I'm behind the graphic design of a widget. The idea is that you first download the app, which will help you to configure the widget, and then you have to manually place the widget in place.

They are afraid that some people wont understand, and they will cease trying.

I only would like to know if this is possible, (or something similar) and if someone knows any APP that does this thingie.

Note: APPS like "Swiftkey" guides you in the process of installing your keyboard. it asks you to go to a determinate place of the phone settings, and gives you a shortcut to that place so you don't have to go by yourself.

It would be amazing. To directly place a widget o to guide them trhough shortcuts.

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible?

No. The user installs the app widget through the home screen.

> The idea is that you first download the app, which will help you to configure the widget, and then you have to manually place the widget in place.

That is also not possible. The flow is that the user chooses the app widget in the home screen, places the widget in place, *then* if you have a configuration activity defined, you will get a chance to help the user configure the app widget (e.g., to choose the city for the weather report that the app widget should display).

> APPS like "Swiftkey" guides you in the process of installing your keyboard. it asks you to go to a determinate place of the phone settings, and gives you a shortcut to that place so you don't have to go by yourself.

Input method editors (a.k.a., soft keyboards) are configured through the Settings app, and therefore there is a consistent place to direct users towards. App widgets are configured through the home screen, and different home screens can implement that process in different ways, so there is no standard spot to direct the users towards.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you.
Could you please expand the comment you did about the flow?
¿Did i understood that i can place an icon in the homescreen that will pull a widget, and then we can help user through widget configuration?

Comment: @Oxyd_: "Could you please expand the comment you did about the flow?" -- I would recommend that you buy an Android device and try using it, to see how app widgets work. "that i can place an icon in the homescreen that will pull a widget" -- no. App widgets usually have their own roster on the home screen that the user pulls from. The details of that will vary by home screen implementation, of which there are hundreds, if not thousands. Again, understanding the flow of using app widgets will be improved you have an Android device and actually use app widgets.

Comment: I do have an android device, and i know the usual way to pull widgets. 
The problem we found is that the widget we are developing (me as a ui designer) requires too much steps to install. specially that process to pull the widget. I know it's a pretty simple process, but this widget is focused on people who seems that is not very good at playing with android stuff, and we are afraid we could lose some clients if they get lost during the configuration. This is why i've been looking for some alternatives, wich seems it is not possible. Many many thanks.

Comment: @Oxyd_: The only way to simplify the app widget setup flow is to implement your own home screen that supports app widgets and to implement your simpler setup flow there. Creating your own home screen is certainly doable -- there are plenty of home screen implementations on the Play Store, for example -- though it is not especially easy, particularly supporting app widgets. Also, your user base may or may not be interested in using your home screen implementation.